# zgemm's conjugate transpose option does not seem to work

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, complex-numbers, blas

I am trying to multiply a complex vector to a complex matrix using the zgemm function of the BLAS library in C.

This is the code I am using:

```
void dot(complexArray* mat1, char transa, complexArray* mat2, char transb, complexArray* out)
{
ptrdiff_t m = (ptrdiff_t)mat1->m;
ptrdiff_t n = (ptrdiff_t)mat2->n;
ptrdiff_t k = (ptrdiff_t)mat1->n;

ptrdiff_t lda = (ptrdiff_t)mat1->m;
ptrdiff_t ldb = (ptrdiff_t)mat2->m;
ptrdiff_t ldc = (ptrdiff_t)out->m;

//scalar factors
double alpha[2] = {1,0};
double beta[2] = {0,0};

//BLAS routine for complex matrix multiplication
zgemm(&transa, &transb, &m, &n, &k, alpha, mat1->data, &lda, mat2->data, 
        &ldb, beta, out->data, &ldc);
}
```

The complexArray struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
double* data;
size_t m;
size_t n;
} complexArray;
```

However, if I call the dot-function by

```
dot(array1, 'C', array2, 'N', resultArray);
```

where array1.m == r, array1.n == 1 and array2.m == array2.n == r, I receive something like

```
216692908932268360000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0000 + 4451969616001722900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0000i
```

Since using the same function with argument 'N' also for variable transa (of course for differently shaped vector/matrix combinations), I am worried that I misunderstood the transa parameter. Any hints where the error could be located?

Comment: And the `data` for `out` has been properly allocated?

Comment: I would say so: All complexArray data get allocated the same way: $data = (double*)mxMalloc(2*m*n*sizeof(double));$. And in this case, m==n==1; thus, a double array with two fields is allocated in order to store both real and imaginary part of the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think I have found the answer in the FORTRAN documentation of the BLAS function (see e.g. [dgemm documentation](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-blas/dgemm.html):

The parameters M, N and K (in my case m, n and k) do not refer to the rows and columns of the original matrices, but to the eventually used matrices, i.e. the transposed or conjugated ones. Therefore, if you use the 'T' or 'C' option for the TRANSA or TRANSB argument, make sure you also swap M and N or N and K, respectively.